# Php not handling logic of true and false correctly

Tags: php

I'm trying to register a new username in an empty table in my database. So I pass in the username and UID and check to see if the user has that name registered already and accept the request or if nobody has the name I can accept it. If there name is registered to another user i reject the request.

It always returns 'Fail' from this bit of code below.

```
    if($name_found) 
    {
    if ($udid_mismatch)
    {
    echo "Fail";
    }
```

But the table of this DB is empty so it cannot be true that it finds the name or UID. Can anybody see my mistake? I'm running in circles at the moment.

```
// Localize the GET variables
$udid   = isset($_GET['udid']) ? $_GET['udid'] : "";
$name   = isset($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name']  : "";


// Protect against sql injections
$udid  = mysql_real_escape_string($udid);
$name  = mysql_real_escape_string($name);



    $udid_mismatch=false;
$name_found=false;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT udid FROM ir_usernames WHERE name='$name'");
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ){
    $name_found=true;
    if($row['udid'] != $udid){
    $udid_mismatch=true;
    }
    break;
}

    if($name_found) 
    {
    if ($udid_mismatch)
    {
    echo "Fail";
    } 
    else 
    {
    echo "Success";
    }
    } else {

// Insert the username
$retval = mysql_query("INSERT INTO $table(
        udid,
        name
    ) VALUES (
        '$udid',
        '$name'
    )",$conn);

if($retval) {
    echo "Success";
} else {
    echo "Fail_ret";
}
}
mysql_close($conn);
```

Many Thanks,
-Code

Comment: Are you sure the table is empty?

Comment: Hi Matthieu, would you mind pointing out what you think shouldn't be there? I'm eager to learn from the guys who know better. Thanks -Code

Comment: @Code Well the main thing is the indentation: I had to read the `if` block at least 3 times to be sure to get it right. You can miss some basic mistakes because of that. The `while` loop is unecessary, you have a `break` at the end of the loop. Change it for a `if` and remove the break, a while is a nonsense here. But seriously, indentation ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems fine , however i see difference in the way your select and insert queries are done. One uses the `$table` variable and the other doesn't. For the sake of harmony, can you try something like:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT udid FROM $table WHERE name='$name'" , $conn);
```

Also it might be a good idea to try this for debugging purposes.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE name='$name'" , $conn);
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ){
   print_r($row);
   // other code
}
```

This would dump out the whole data, which would give you some hint on whats going on.

Answer (score 1):

You said "I'm trying to register a new username in an empty table in my database." However, $name_found will always be false if no records are returned by the query. Since it is being set to true (evidenced by the eventual output of "Fail") you must have at least one record in your table.

Please examine your data to determine if there is a matching record in the table.

Comment: Table has 0 rows! Triple checked.

Comment: Something is changing `$name_found` to `true`. There are two things to check. First, insert an echo statement into the `while()` loop to see if it ever runs. Second, check your code for anything (not posted here) that would change the value of `$name_found`.

Comment: I second @George, some basic debugging with var_dump should tell you all you need to know (or at least give much more infos). StackOverfow is not "debug that code please"

Answer (score 1):

Could it be the missing concatenation?

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT udid FROM ir_usernames WHERE name='".$name."'");
```

Comment: The OP's syntax on that line should be fine, PHP will expand variables in double-quoted strings.